# Is there a javascript library to annotate on images and save the annotations as image in the server?

Tags: java, javascript, svg, annotations

I'm looking at Javascript libraries for adding annotations to images in the browser. I've found libraries like [Annotator](http://okfnlabs.org/annotator/demo/) and [Zurb](http://zurb.com/playground/javascript-annotation-plugin), but none of these provide the option to save the annotations as an image on the server side. My plan is to superimpose the annotations on the original image in the back end so that the user can download the annotated image. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok guys..here's how I ended up doing it..This info might come in handy for someone else in the future..I couldn't find any library that provides the option to save the annotations as an image in the server side. I used Raphael JS library to create my own UI for adding annotations in the client side(as SVG). Then I send the SVG content to the server side, convert it into a image using Apache Batik library, overlay it on top the original image(that the user annotated on) and let the user download the combined image.

Comment: Is this available as open source somewhere? :D